# Xdebug - Joonty vdebug switching between windows

Tags: vim, xdebug

So I am debugging my php app with xdebug and https://github.com/joonty/vdebug/ as my vim plugin. When I hit get the debug running i get 4 windows. In other vim plugins I was able to switch between these windows so i could scroll up and down in case the data became too big. I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Anyone know how to switch between windows with xdebug using vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just split window, you can read about it here

```
:h window-move-cursor
```

To make it more simple put this mapping into your vimrc

```
nnoremap <C-J> <C-W><C-J>
nnoremap <C-K> <C-W><C-K>
nnoremap <C-L> <C-W><C-L>
nnoremap <C-H> <C-W><C-H>
```

Now just press `ctrl-J` to get to window below current one, etc.

Comment: this is perfect. Thank you so much